# How to create Xauthority file?

Tags: sudo, nautilus

I am trying to run nautilus with `gksudo nautilus`. However, whenever I try, this dialog appears:

[image]

Along with the following message in the terminal:

> Error copying '/home/.../.Xauthority' to '/tmp/libgksu-v8QBGW': No
>   such file or directory

Then I tried to create a new ~/.Xauthority file by `sudo touch ~/.Xauthority`. Once I run `gksudo nautilus`, a dialog asks for my password (also, I cannot write in the textbox, only paste. So I paste my password...)

The following error shows:

> Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
>
> (nautilus:4202): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

I've looked everywhere but cannot find a solution. Also, I cannot open any other visual interface using root, like `gksudo synaptic`, as the same happens. Please help.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w

Comment: Thank you, @muru. I had just solved it by doing "xhost +", then I saw the link you posted, which is more appropriate. I wish I could choose your comment as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

As muru suggested with the [URL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w), doing `xhost si:localuser:root` solved the issue. If he/she wants to answer the question, I will accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Ubuntu. I had a similar issue and found out that GDM is starting two Xorg servers (more detail [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910108/why-is-my-gdm-at-a-different-tty-than-my-desktop-environment)). What this meant for me was that there were two sockets being created in `/tmp/.X11-unix`. The value of env var `$DISPLAY` shows which display `gksudo` and other graphic applications are using when you try to run them as root from the terminal.

The value ':0' is now pointing to the greeter Xorg instance and the actual user Xorg session is now located at ':1'.

Double check `ps aux | grep Xorg` then `ls /tmp/.X11-unix` to see what I mean and if this applies to you. If it does, simply changing the value of $DISPLAY to be ':1' upon login to thwart these display errors is preferred to 
`xhost si:localuser:root` which can compromise X11 security.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did what you said and got the error `(gksudo:16130): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 1`. When I do `ls /tmp/.X11-unix`, I get: `X0  X1024`. So, even changing DISPLAY=1024 gets me the same error.